# AngularJS - run check against elements as they come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just followed this 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/QL28C/1/) example to create a little search box from an array object in my javascript. Now after some tweaking and research on `search.object` and `filter:search:strict`. Now that I have it filtering correctly, I modified a checkbox in the template that is checked upon loading the document and switched on or off based on a custom data attribute in the html that is updated by the json array.

How do I run this check once someone clears the search and the old items show back up again?

In the HTML I have this template

```
<div ng-repeat="o in objects | filter:search:strict | orderBy:'obj_name'" class="objectContainer">
<h3>{{o.obj_name}}</h3>
    <label class="userToggleSwitch" >
        <input class="userToggleInput" data-isactive="{{o.obj_isactive}}" type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

In the JS

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){

angular.module('searchApp',[])
    .controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope','objHolder',function ($scope,objHolder) {
        $scope.search = '';
        $scope.objects = [];

        $scope.objects = objHolder.getobjects();

    }])
    // fake service, substitute with your server call ($http)
    .factory('objHolder',function(){
        var objects = objList;
        return {

            getobjects : function(){
                return objects;
            }
        };
    });
});
```

The JS that modifies the items on document load is using jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//console.log($('.userToggleInput'));
$.each($('.userToggleInput'), function(){

if($(this).data("isactive") == 1){$(this).attr('checked', true);}
if($(this).data("isactive") == 0){$(this).attr('checked', false);}
})

$('.userToggleInput').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == undefined) {

        // THIS IS WHERE WE WILL MAKE AN AJAX CALL TO A PHP CLASS 
        // TO REQUEST IF THE USER CAN BE TURNED ON - DUE TO LIC RESTRICTIONS
        $(this).attr('checked',true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked',false);
    }
    //console.log($(this).attr('checked'));

});
});
```

[Created JS Fiddle to assist in Helping in this manner](https://jsfiddle.net/NGMDev/5v4vhdzc/3/)

Comment: you should do some preprocessing in the factory once you get the objList, that way in your ng-repeat you have access to a new property, for example, isChecked. now in your template use ng-model and assign the property o.isChecked.

Comment: Show your code in fiddle and avoid jQuery in angular.

Comment: you should be using angular rather than jquery. The code you've shown can be completely done in angular

Comment: Use the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to control the state of the checkbox. See [AngularJS input checkbox Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: Use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to execute Angular Expressions when inputs change.

Comment: Please see JS Fiddle I created that doesn't have all the working css. But it will work for concept. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v4vhdzc/)

Comment: @PratyushPranjal - Please see updated Post